# Работа с указателями

Tags: delphi, указатели

Есть класс TPlace:

```
TPlace = class(TPanel)
  public
    pNum: TPanel;
    pNumGallon: TPanel;
    pPGS: TPanel;
  end;
```

Есть родительская панель, на которой находятся несколько объектов TPlace, объектов других классов на родительской панели нет. При щелчке мышью на дочернем объекте, он записывается в переменную SelectedPlace. Также на форме есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую должен выводиться Caption следующего за выбранным элемента.

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   aPlace: ^TPlace;
begin
   aPlace := @SelectedPlace;
   inc(aPlace);
   ShowMessage(TPlace(aPlace^).Caption);
end;
```

На строке `"ShowMessage(TPlace(aPlace^).pNum.Caption);"` выскакивает access violation. Т.е. не удается преобразовать элемент, хранящийся по новому адресу в TPlace. Где ошибка? В коде или в ДНК? :) Неужели элементы массива хранятся не по порядку?

Comment: В классе TPlace, к клику привязывается функция вот таким макаром:

@OnClick := @FindInGrid;

В самой функции переменной SelectedPlace присваивается адрес кликнутого объекта:

SelectedPlace := TPlace(TPanel(Sender).Parent);

Про инкремент написал ниже.

Comment: `@OnClick := @FindInGrid;` ... где так написано делать???

Answer (score 2):

> Неужели элементы массива хранятся не по порядку

Покажите, где тут массивы.

> inc(aPlace);

Вы увеличиваете адрес в указателе на 1. Это как минимум неработоспособно, потому как объект явно не один байт занимает. Кроме того, если вы уже выбрали последний элемент, какой должен идти за ним? Так что инкремент вам не нужен совсем.

Объявите лучше **настоящий** **массив** на 3 элемента. И обращайтесь по индексу. Можно даже с инкрементом (только не забывайте инкрементировать по модулю 3).

Comment: Ну во-первых указатель типизированный, поэтому инкремент увеличивает адрес не на единицу, а на размер структуры, а точнее объекта класса. (вот например в этой статье описывается: http://www.igrif.org/programmizm/ukazateli-v-delphi/)

Comment: Во-вторых массив здесь уже есть - это набор контролов, о чем ясно говорится в справке по делфи:

Description
Controls is an array of all the child controls. These are all controls that list this control as their Parent property. The Controls property is convenient for referring to the children of a control by number rather than name. For example, Controls may be used to iterate over all the child controls.

Comment: В третьих - да, тут возможна ошибка, если я выберу последний контрол на родительской панели (спасибо, за замечание, исправлю), но эта ошибка возникает, когда я кликаю на любом из дочерних объектов родительской формы.

Вопрос не в том, чтобы решить задачу. А в том, чтобы разобраться, почему этот пример с указателями не работает.

Вроде все описал. Где не прав?

Comment: > во-первых указатель типизированный

Да, верно. Подзапарил про арифметику указателей.

> Во-вторых массив здесь уже есть - это набор контролов, о чем ясно говорится в справке по делфи: Description *Controls* is an array of all the child controls

Тогда вы должны им  явно пользоваться (там говорится про конкретный массив с именем Controls). Вы же обращаетесь к полям класса, а не к массиву.

    self.Controls[i];

Проблема только может возникнет, если кроме трех панелей будут еще контролы на форме.

Comment: Можно поподробней про обращение к массиву, а не к свойству?

Я не очень понял - к каким полям какого класса я обращаюсь? Где вы увидели обращение к полям класса?

В переменной SelectedPlace хранится адрес объекта TPlace, который является наследником от TPanel. Если не инкрементировать этот адрес, то caption выводится нормально - проверял. По идее, увеличив адрес на размер объекта типа TPlace, я получу адрес следующего элемента в массиве Controls (если конечно они действительно хранятся по порядку), т.к. дочерних объектов другого типа на родительской панели нет...

Comment: В комментарии предыдущего оратора описал процесс присваивания переменной SelectedPlace адреса выбраннного объекта TPlace, может быть наведет на мысль.

Comment: Учитывая, что TPlace уже является указателем, брать от него указатель и адрес - как минимум показывать свою безграмотность.
С другой стороны, никто не гарантирует Вам, что объекты будут находиться в памяти именно так, как Вам кажется. Они к примеру могут храниться в связанном списке. А высокоуровневые методы будут предоставлять интерфейс обращения в виде массива.

Не пишите код на делфи, как будто это ассемблер для pdp-11. Пишите на делфи. Не устраивает производительность - пишите на другом языке.